# Issues re-importing exported (and corrected) product file from Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1 to Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2, product-import

*We have way too many problems with our Magento 2.4.2-p1.* I believe this has to do with the fact that we used the Magento Migration Tool to Migrate from Magento 1.9.4.

I decided to install a fresh install of the currently available Magento version = 2.4.3-p1 and export/import products, orders, and customers manually, then set up the theme and at the very end install our Amasty's extensions.

The first thing I did is I exported the Products from Magento 2.4.2-p1 by following these steps:

**System -> Data Transfer - Export**

where

```
Entity Type = Products
Export File Format = CSV (the only option)
Field Enclosure = Yes (ticked)
```

When I tried to re-import this file into the freshly installed Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1. - I got almost 100 Errors which mostly had to do with Duplicate URLs and long thumbnail and meta descriptions. I have corrected all of these and the only Error which came up said the following (when doing Check Data):

Validation Results:
Checked rows: 201, checked entities: 2529, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 1

Following Error(s) has been occurred during the importing process:
Only the first 100 errors are shown. Download full report

**Error in CSV: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded**
Additional data:

The file is valid! To start the import process press "Import" button

[image]

When I click the Import button, the following error comes up:

Maximum error count has been reached or a system error has occurred!
Following Error(s) has been occurred during the importing process:
Only the first 100 errors are shown. Download full report

```
General system exception happened
Additional data: <div class="messages"><div class="message message-error error"><div data-ui-id="messages-message-error" >File directory '/home/ouraccountnameonserver/public_html/var/import/images/pub/media/catalog/product' is not readable.</div></div></div>
```

I checked via FTP and the furthest this path exists on the new Magento installation is:

**/public_html/var/import/images**

I did, however, specify a different directory on the Import page:

**pub/media/catalog/product**

(That's where I uploaded the product photos from Magento 2.4.2-p1.)

***What do I need to do to make this work?***

I also noticed that in the Excel .csv spreadsheet it showed funny characters in places where we had an apostrophe (') in the thumbnail or meta description. I corrected the ones that were mentioned in the Errors but there are others that remain - *does that need to be fixed?*

Also, some of our SKUs have spaces in them. *Do I need to go through and remove them?*